# Is there a way to stop a SearchView widget from collapsing

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` that has two vertical layouts.  The left layout contains a `SearchView` widget and a `ListView`,  the right a `TextView`.
The search widget, on user input, searches a `SQLite3` database and returns a list of titles from the database to the `ListView`.   The user can select from the `ListView` a title and the titles details are displayed in the right `TextView`.
This works fine, however when the user selects from the `ListView` the `SearchView` collapses (losing user input) and the `ListView` data disappears.
I have struggled to find a way to retain the user input (and therefore the `ListView`) when the user selects a title from the `ListView`.
Can someone please point me in the right direction??.  Is it because of a change in focus?, I have tried several iconified ideas but don't seem able to find a solution.

Comment: how do you perform the filtering?

Comment: Using a SQLite SELECT statement on the database taking from user input into the SearchView as a LIKE statement, with a '%' added to make the user input as a prefix to the search.

Comment: i meant the code you are using

Comment: Ah right, development is using Android Studio 1.2.2 so IntelliJ built with gradle, hope this is what you are meaning.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by putting the SearchView into a separate layout from the listview.  Not sure why this resolved it but app is now displaying as I require.